# Piping unzip in a SAS infile

Tags: xml, pipe, sas

Suppose I do the following in SAS:

```
filename  tmp pipe 'unzip -c -qq ./data_xml.zip';
libname   tmp xml xmlmap=TMMap access=READONLY;

data header; set tmp.header; run;
data owners; set tmp.owners; run;
```

This will unzip the `data_xml.zip` file and use the SAS `xmlmap` file to generate two data sets, `header` and `owners`.

My question is, how many times will unzip run on `data_xml.zip`? Will the unzipping just happen once, or will it happen twice because I'm setting a data set from the `tmp` libname twice?

Comment: Can you infer this by looking at a performance monitor on the server, and placing a pause between the two data steps? My money is on twice.

Comment: If you want to make sure it only unzips once, I would suggest using an X "O/S command line" statement to unzip the file before defining the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, YES, it will unzip it twice.

As I understand it, the `unzip -c` essentially turns that data into a sequential source because it is streaming from the unzip command directly into the `PIPE` libname.

Presumably, you want to stream via the `-c` and the `PIPE` because of disk space and/or performance concerns with landing the file to disk first.  Unfortunately, I'm fairly certain that the way things are set up, the only way to minimize the CPU of an additional unzip will be to land it to disk on a temporary file first.

However, depending on the size of the file, the CPU hit for a second unzip might not outweigh the I/O hit for having to read an expanded file from disk at least one extra time.